# .htaccess variable not passover

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I the modrewrites to work to pass
`haha.domain.com`
to `domain.com/master5.php?userid=haha`

but I cannot pass the subdomain to more controllers like
`haha.domain.com/33/44`
to `domain.com/master5.php?userid=haha&pid=33&wid=44`

here's my code below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/profile.php?username=%2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ http://www.domain.com/master5.php?username=%2&$1&$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ http://www.domain.com/master5.php?username=%2&$1&$2 [L]
```

Comment: Passover is coming up, yes it is. :P

Comment: Or Pesach, as they say in Hebrew...

Comment: `haha.domain.com` -- isn't that more for Purim?

Comment: In all seriousness, I can't figure out the title or the question. Also, this doesn't look programming-related.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding QSA (Query String Append) to the RewriteRules: `[L,QSA]`.